# Prove that the action of the Homemorphism of the plane is n transitive for all n

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am trying to prove that the action of $Homeo(\mathbb{R}²)$ on the plane is $n-$transitive for all $n$.

Given $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ points of the plane, the idea was trying to prove that the action of the subgroup of $Homeo(\mathbb{R}^2)$ that fixes this points is transitive on $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{p_1,...,p_n\} $ and that this is valid for any $n$. I try using polynomials to write maps that has no effect in the fixed points (i.e the polynomials has a root here) and that are basicly traslation far away from this points. The problem is that I failed to get a bijection.

For simplicity, I tried writing my maps as complex maps, from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Also I would like to extend this reasoning to $S^2$, but I am convinced that this is just an adaption

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can define a homotopy of points, carrying one set of points to the other — that is, disjoint paths connecting both sets. It’s a theorem that this homotopy can be extend to a homeomorphism of the whole plane. The buzzword here is “point pushing map.”

Comment: I get you point, but there is not a more elementary way to do this? I am not supposed to know about this point pushing map

Comment: I suppose this is asking whether or not there’s some homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2-\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2-\{q_1,\dots,q_n\}$ that can be extended to a homeomorphism of the un-cut-up spaces.

Comment: Yes. That is a way to see it

Comment: At the end I am convinced to use the point pushing map. The reason is that I ask for a hint in my university and we end up pratically proving the point pushing map. When I have time I am going to try to put this ideas formally (the proof of the point pushing map..) and I am going to give an answer! Thanks for the Idea!